# Mathematica collect a common factor not yet explicit

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have an expression of the form

x^2Coth[y] + 2xyCoth[y] + y^2Coth[y],

this is equal to

(x - y)^2Coth[y].

Is there a way to ask Mathematica to do this collection? That is, something like

Collect[x^2Coth[y] + 2xyCoth[y] + y^2Coth[y], x - y]

giving output (x - y)^2Coth[y] ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This uses [Rojo's solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/14754/363).  There may be a simpler way.

```
expr = x^2 Coth[y] + 2 x y Coth[y] + y^2 Coth[y];

var = Coth[y];

doThat[expr_, vars_List] := Expand[Simplify[
     expr /. Flatten[Solve[# == ToString@#, First@Variables@#] & /@ vars]],
    Alternatives @@ ToString /@ vars] /. Thread[ToString /@ vars -> vars];

doThat[expr, {var}]

(* (x + y)^2 Coth[y] *)
```

**Edit**

Indeed there is a simpler way:

```
Collect[expr, var, Factor]

(* (x + y)^2 Coth[y] *)
```